# How to convert from File to String?

Tags: flutter, dart

I am new to flutter and dart, I don't have much work with this language
I have a button in which the user has to upload a pdf file and I need to be able to manage the information, therefore I want to convert it to a string to be able to use that information, I have the following method

```
`void handleFileChange(Event e) async {
    final files = (_fileInput?.files ?? []);
    if (files.isNotEmpty) {
      final file = files.first;
      final reader = FileReader();
      reader.readAsArrayBuffer(file);
      reader.onLoadEnd.listen((event) {
        final Uint8List? result = reader.result as Uint8List?;
        if (result != null) {
          try {
            final String pdfContentString = latin1.decode(result);
            print(pdfContentString.toString());
          } catch (e) {
            print('Error al decodificar los datos binarios como UTF-8: $e');
          }
        }
      });
    }
}
`
```

The problem is that I can't get the text that the pdf has, any idea how to solve this?

Edit: This is all the code

```
import 'dart:async';
import 'dart:html';
import 'dart:convert';
import 'dart:typed_data';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import 'package:pruebachecbox/subir_pdf.dart';
import 'Validador.dart';

class CentroClientes extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State<CentroClientes> createState() => _CentroClientesState();
}

class _CentroClientesState extends State<CentroClientes> {
  final CollectionReference val = FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('Clientes');
  final GlobalKey<FormState> _formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();
  String storage = "Clientes";
  String sub = "Csf";
  late FileUploadInputElement _fileInput;
  File? _selectedPDF;
  SubirPDF sb = SubirPDF();
  String _urlpdf = "";
  List<String> _csf = [];
  List<String> _alertas = [];
  Validador va = Validador();
  String? _pdfContent;
  late StreamController<Map<String, dynamic>> _documentStreamController;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _documentStreamController = StreamController<Map<String, dynamic>>();
    listenForDocumentChanges();
    _fileInput = FileUploadInputElement()..id = 'file_picker';
    _fileInput.accept = 'application/pdf';
    _fileInput.style.display = 'none';
    _fileInput.onChange.listen(handleFileChange);
    document.body?.children.add(_fileInput);
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _fileInput.remove();
    super.dispose();
  }

  void listenForDocumentChanges() {
    FirebaseFirestore.instance
        .collection('Clientes')
        .snapshots()
        .map((snapshot) => snapshot.docs.map((doc) => doc.data()).toList())
        .listen((data) {
      _documentStreamController.add(data.first);
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
          body: Container(
            child: SingleChildScrollView(
              child: Column(
                children: [
                  Container(
                    width: double.infinity,
                    color: Colors.white,
                    child: Padding(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
                      child: Form(
                        key: _formKey,
                        child: SingleChildScrollView(
                          child: Column(
                            children: [
                              Container(
                                color: Color.fromRGBO(230, 230, 230, 1.0),
                                child: const Row(
                                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                                  children: [
                                    Text(
                                      'Crear Cliente',
                                      style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20),
                                    ),
                                  ],
                                ),
                              ),
                              StreamBuilder<Map<String, dynamic>>(
                                stream: _documentStreamController.stream,
                                builder: (context, snapshot) {
                                  if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
                                    return Center(
                                      child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
                                    );
                                  }
                                  if (snapshot.hasError) {
                                    print("error: ${snapshot.error}");
                                    return Text('Error al cargar los datos');
                                  }

                                  Map<String, dynamic> documentData = snapshot.data!;
                                  _csf = extractWords(documentData['CSF']);
                                  return Column(
                                    children: [
                                      Column(
                                        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                                        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                                        children: [
                                          IgnorePointer(
                                            ignoring: _csf[0].toUpperCase() != "EMPTY" && _csf[0].toUpperCase() != "NOTEMPTY",
                                            child: InkWell(
                                              onTap: pickPDF,
                                              child: Container(
                                                padding: EdgeInsets.all(10),
                                                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                                  border: Border.all(color: Colors.grey),
                                                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5),
                                                ),
                                                child: Row(
                                                  children: [
                                                    Icon(Icons.upload_file),
                                                    SizedBox(width: 10),
                                                    Text(
                                                      _selectedPDF != null
                                                          ? 'Archivo PDF seleccionado: ${_selectedPDF!.name}'
                                                          : '${_csf[4]}',
                                                    ),

                                                  ],
                                                ),
                                              ),
                                            ),
                                          ),
                                          SizedBox(height: 5),
                                          if (_csf[0].toUpperCase() == "EMPTY" || _csf[0].toUpperCase() == "NOTEMPTY")
                                            SizedBox.shrink()
                                          else
                                            Text(
                                              'Descripción del documento error de configuración, comuníquese con el administrador de la base de datos',
                                              style: TextStyle(color: Colors.red),
                                            ),
                                          if (_selectedPDF != null) ...[
                                            Column(
                                              children: [
                                                Row(
                                                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                                                  children: [
                                                    ElevatedButton(
                                                      onPressed: () async {
                                                        if (_formKey.currentState!.validate()) {
                                                          if (_selectedPDF != null) {
                                                            _urlpdf = (await sb.uploadPDF(_selectedPDF!))!;
                                                          }
                                                          if (_selectedPDF?.name != null) {
                                                            await verificarCampoUnico(_csf[2], "CSF", _selectedPDF!.name, 'El campo CSF ya está dada de alta');
                                                          }
                                                          if (_alertas.isNotEmpty) {
                                                            ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(
                                                              SnackBar(
                                                                backgroundColor: Colors.red,
                                                                content: Column(
                                                                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                                                                  mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                                                                  children: _alertas.map((mensaje) => Text(mensaje)).toList(),
                                                                ),
                                                                duration: Duration(seconds: 3),
                                                              ),
                                                            );
                                                            _alertas.clear();
                                                            return;
                                                          }
                                                          _sendDataToFirebase();
                                                          ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(
                                                            const SnackBar(
                                                              backgroundColor: Colors.green,
                                                              content: Text('Informacion subida correctamente'),
                                                              duration: Duration(seconds: 5),
                                                            ),
                                                          );
                                                        } else if (_selectedPDF != null) {
                                                          ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(
                                                            const SnackBar(
                                                              backgroundColor: Colors.red,
                                                              content: Text('Hay error con algun dato'),
                                                              duration: Duration(seconds: 3),
                                                            ),
                                                          );
                                                        } else if (_csf[0].toUpperCase() == "NOTEMPTY" && _selectedPDF == null) {
                                                          ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(
                                                            const SnackBar(
                                                              backgroundColor: Colors.red,
                                                              content: Text('Aun no has seleccionado La constancia de situacion fiscal'),
                                                              duration: Duration(seconds: 3),
                                                            ),
                                                          );
                                                        }
                                                      },
                                                      child: Text('Enviar'),
                                                    ),
                                                    ElevatedButton(
                                                      onPressed: () {},
                                                      child: Text('Cancelar'),

                                                    ),
                                                  ],
                                                ),
                                                    SizedBox(height: 10), // Espacio entre los botones y el contenido del PDF


                                              ],
                                            ),
                                          ],
                                        ],
                                      ),
                                    ],
                                  );
                                },
                              ),
                            ],
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
    );
  }
  Future<void> verificarCampoUnico(String vali, String nombreCampo, String valor, String mensajeDuplicado) async {
    if (vali.toUpperCase() == "UNICO") {
      bool existe = await va.verificarIdExistente(nombreCampo, valor, val);
      if (existe) {
        _alertas.add(mensajeDuplicado);
      }
    }
  }

  List<String> extractWords(String input) {
    return input.replaceAll(RegExp(r'[{}]+'), '').split(',').map((word) => word.trim()).toList();
  }

  //pdf a bites y quedarnos solo con el text
  void handleFileChange(Event e) async {
    final files = (_fileInput?.files ?? []);
    if (files.isNotEmpty) {
      final file = files.first;
      final reader = FileReader();
      reader.readAsArrayBuffer(file);
      reader.onLoadEnd.listen((event) {
        final Uint8List? result = reader.result as Uint8List?;
        if (result != null) {
          print(result); // Imprimir los datos binarios en la consola para identificar el problema
          try {
            final String pdfContentString = latin1.decode(result);
            print(pdfContentString);// Aquí imprime el contenido del PDF en formato de texto legible para humanos
          } catch (e) {
            print('Error al decodificar los datos binarios como UTF-8: $e');
          }
        }
      });
    }
  }
  void pickPDF() {
    _fileInput?.click();
  }

  void _sendDataToFirebase() {
    FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('Clientes').add({
      'CFS': _urlpdf,
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: Are you getting error or extracted text is not meaningful? Directly converting the binary content of a PDF file into a string won't give you meaningful text because a PDF file contains structured data, not plain text.

Answer (score 0):

you can use packages like pdf or flutter_pdfview combined with flutter_full_pdf_viewer.

Add the pdf package to your pubspec.yaml file, and run **flutter pub get** to install the package.

```
dependencies:
  pdf: ^2.0.0-dev.4
```

Then import required packages:

```
import 'dart:io';
import 'package:pdf/pdf.dart';
import 'package:pdf/widgets.dart' as pw;
```

Your code should be something like that:

```
void handleFileChange(Event e) async {
  final files = (_fileInput?.files ?? []);
  if (files.isNotEmpty) {
    final file = files.first;
    final pdf = pw.Document();

    // Load PDF file
    final pdfBytes = await file.readAsBytes();

    // Parse PDF
    final pdfDocument = PdfDocument.openData(pdfBytes);

    // Extract text from each page
      for (var page in pdfDocument.pages) {
        final pageText = await page.text;
        print(pageText);
      }
  }
}
```

Comment: I had already tried something like this, but the code shows me an error
readAsBytes , saying the following

he method 'readAsBytes' isn't defined for the type 'File'. (Documentation) Try correcting the name to the name of an existing method, or defining a method named 'readAsBytes'.

And then in .openData(pdfBytes) it tells me the following error

he method 'openData' isn't defined for the type 'PdfDocument'. (Documentation) Try correcting the name to the name of an existing method, or defining a method named 'openData'.

Comment: Should you edit question with full code? it is not clear where fileInput comes from? What type is it?